# comment_reply_link with svg icon instead of reply_text

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to replace the Reply text with an SVG icon.

So far my code for the SVG icon function

```
<?php echo malinki_get_icon_svg( 'browser' );?>
```

and the comment_reply_text

```php
<?php
comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array(
    'add_below' => 'div-comment',
    'depth' => $depth,
    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
    'reply_text' => __('Antworten'),
    'before' => '<span class="comment-reply">',
    'after' => '</span>'
)));
?>
```

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG icon function returns the icon correctly, you could use code like this in your theme's functions.php file:

```
/**
* Change the comment reply link
*
* @param array   $args
* @param object  $comment
* @param object  $post
* @return array $args
*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'malinki_comment_reply_link' ) ) :
    add_filter( 'comment_reply_link_args', 'malinki_comment_reply_link', 10, 3 );
    function malinki_comment_reply_link( $args, $comment, $post ) {

        $args['reply_text'] = malinki_get_icon_svg( 'browser' );

        return $args;
    }
endif;
```

The important thing to know is that in this case you need to use the `comment_reply_link_args` filter.